# Detect Property Change upon delete from textbox

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, mvvm

Im using WPF and VB.Net under MVVM pattern.

I am trying to edit records fetch from database. My textbox is binded in my property in viewmodel when I highlight the text then press backspace from keyboard, I notice that it does not detect that the value in textbox has been removed. Am I forgetting something?

Here is my XAML:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding TimeTaken,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" TextChanged="txt_TextChanged" Style="{StaticResource DialogTextBox}"  Height="23" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2"/>
```

Here is my property from ViewModel:

```
    Public Property TimeTaken As Single
    Get
        Return Me.GetPropertyValue(Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.Name)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Single)
        Me.SetPropertyValue(Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.Name, value)
    End Set
End Property
```

I only encounter it when deleting using highlight. But when I delete per text changes will be set.

Comment: Doesn't `Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.Name` return `Single` when you should be using `SingleProperty`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you binding to  Text(String) <-> Single  , 
It Handles input of text and Casts (Single) on them , when giving an empty.string the cast returns nothing . 
You can use a converter  ..  But the real question is why aren't you binding to a String type property since at the end you set a Name property of some object in your setter .